# Find values of $k$, $l$, and $m$ such that the following equation is satisfied

Tags: equation-solving, numerical-value

I am trying to find the (numerical) subset of $(k,l,m)\in[-\pi,\pi)\times[-\pi,\pi)\times[-\pi,\pi)$ 
where the next expression is valid
$$
  \tan \Bigl(
    \frac{k+l+m}{2}
\Bigr)
=
\frac{ \sin k+ \sin l+\sin m }{ \cos k+ \cos l+\cos m }.
$$
When I fix $k$ I am able, using `ContourPlot`, to
obtain a set of curves revealing where the previous
expression is satisfied. However, I'd like to get not a
curve but the values of $l$ and $m$.

Note that using `NSolve` returns "This system cannot be solved
with the methods available to Solve.". `NMinimize` only gives
a point on the curve.

Comment: `findM[k_,l_] := FindRoot[Tan[(k + l + m)/2] - (Sin[k] + Sin[l] + Sin[m])/(
    Cos[k] + Cos[l] + Cos[m]) == 0, {m, 0, -π, π}][[1, 2]]`?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[Tan[(k+l+m)/2]-(Sin[k]+Sin[l]+Sin[m])/(Cos[k]+Cos[l]+Cos[m])==0, {k,-π,π}, {l,-π,π}, {m,-π,π}]` gives a good overview of the solution branches.

Comment: @Roman There is only 1 branch. The rest are artifacts due to diverging `tan` function. It is better to use `ContourPlot3D[Tan[(k + l + m)/2] (Cos[k] + Cos[l] + Cos[m]) - (Sin[k] + Sin[l] + Sin[m]) == 0, {k, -π, π]}, {l, -π],π}, {m, -π, π]}, 
 RegionFunction -> Function[{k, l, m}, Cos[k + l + m] > -0.98]]`

Comment: You have 3 parameters and only 1 equation. Thus, the solution forms a 2-dimensional surface in 3d space. You cannot use `Solve` for that. In contrast `ContourPlot3D` nicely reveals this surface. A more meaningful and challenging question would be to find a 2d parametrization of this surface.

Comment: Please, feel free to wrap up these comments into an answer as they solved my question.  @yarchik Yes, definitely that would be nice but I imagine that it would be pretty non-straightforward. I know that I did not ask this in my original question, but is possible to sample the surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some mathematical simplifications are needed before plotting in order to deal with divergencies of $\tan x$ for $x=\frac\pi2+n \pi$, where $n\in \mathbb{Z}$.  One can use that
$$\tan\frac{x+y}{2}=\frac{\sin x+\sin y}{\cos x+\cos y}.$$

The rest is automatic

```
Clear[eq]
eq[0]=(Sin[k]+Sin[l+m])(Cos[k]+Cos[l]+Cos[m])-(Cos[k]+Cos[l+m])(Sin[k]+Sin[l]+Sin[m])
eq[1]=FullSimplify[eq[0]]
eq[2]=TrigFactor[eq[1]]
Out[1]= -(Cos[k]+Cos[l+m]) (Sin[k]+Sin[l]+Sin[m])+(Cos[k]+Cos[l]+Cos[m]) (Sin[k]+Sin[l+m])
Out[2]= Sin[k-l]+Sin[l]+Sin[k-m]-Sin[k-l-m]+Sin[m]
Out[3]= 2 Cos[k/2-l/2-m/2] (-Sin[k/2-l/2-m/2]+Sin[k/2+l/2-m/2]+Sin[k/2-l/2+m/2])
```

The first factor is describing planes $k+l+m=\pi+2n\pi$, where $\tan\frac{k+l+m}{2}$ is diverging. The second factor is a regular solution. Now we plot the two factors

```
ContourPlot3D[Evaluate[{eq[2][[2]]==0,eq[2][[3]]==0}],{k,-π,π},{l,-π,π},{m,-π,π},PlotTheme->{"Minimal"},ContourStyle->{Opacity[0.35],Automatic}]
```

[image]